# Conditional sum in Group By query MSSQL

Tags: sql

I have a table OrderDetails with the following schema:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
|  OrderId  |  CopyCost  |  FullPrice  |  Price  |  PriceType  |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|  16       |  50        |  100        |  50     |  CopyCost   |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|  16       |  50        |  100        |  100    |  FullPrice  |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|  16       |  50        |  100        |  50     |  CopyCost   |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|  16       |  50        |  100        |  50     |  CopyCost   |
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

I need a query that will surmise the above table into a new table with the following schema:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
|  OrderId  |  ItemCount  |  TotalCopyCost  |  TotalFullPrice  |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|  16       |  4          |  150            |  100             |
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Currently I am using a Group By on the Order.Id to the the item count. But I do not know how to conditionally surmise the CopyCost and FullPrice values.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Regards
Freddie

Comment: What are you expecting the outputs to be?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT OrderId, 
       COUNT(*) ItemCount,
       SUM(CASE WHEN PriceType = 'CopyCost' THEN Price ELSE 0 END) TotalCopyCost,
       SUM(CASE WHEN PriceType = 'FullPrice' THEN Price ELSE 0 END) TotalFullPrice
  FROM OrderDetails
 GROUP BY OrderId
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e906c/1)**

Comment: Is there any way to do this if you don't know the price types in advance? For example if the table in question `|  OrderId  |  CopyCost  |  FullPrice  |  Price  |  PriceType  |` would be the result of a join on a `order` table and a `order_price_type` table? The summary table would then have a changing column count depending on how many rows the `order_price_types` table has?

Comment: @Lukasz Any time you don't know the columns to be output in advance, you need to use dynamic sql.

Answer (score 9):

Try this query

```
select 
   orderId, 
   count(*) as cnt, 
   sum(if(pricetype='CopyCost', CopyCost, 0)) as totalCopyCost,
   sum(if(pricetype='FullPrice', FullPrice, 0)) as totalFullPrice
from 
   tbl
group by 
   orderId
```

### **[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6ce07/1)**:

```
| ORDERID | CNT | TOTALCOPYCOST | TOTALFULLPRICE |
--------------------------------------------------
|      16 |   4 |           150 |            100 |
```

Comment: More elegant than CASE, but "if()" is a DAX function: 2008 R2 minimum, non-ANSI. Be careful.

Answer (score 4):

Could you use:

```
SELECT
  OrderId,
  Count(1) as ItemCount,
  SUM(CASE WHEN PriceType = 'CopyCost' 
        THEN CopyCost ELSE 0 END) AS TotalCopyCost,
  SUM(CASE WHEN PriceType = 'FullPrice' 
        THEN FullPrice ELSE 0 END) AS TotalFullPrice
FROM OrderDetails
GROUP BY OrderId
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also try...

```
select A.OrderID, A.ItemCount,B.TotalCopyCost, C.TotalFullPrice
from (select OrderID, count(*) as ItemCount from orderdetails) as A,
(select OrderID, sum(CopyCost) as TotalCopyCost from orderdetails where PriceType = 'CopyCost') as B,
(select OrderID, sum(FullPrice) as TotalFullPrice from orderdetails where PriceType = 'FullPrice') as C
where A.OrderID = B.OrderID
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/946af/6