# SUMIFS (Sum if with multiple conditions) with SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]
This should be done easy in Excel, however, I would like to have this kind of calculation done via SQL. I could use the `GROUP BY` , `OVER()` to calculate the SUM and % of a single year. But I failed to present the data 3 years at once. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I see your graphic, but you give more details about how you'd like it grouped?  Also, what does your original dataset look like?

Comment: I have 3 year 2010, 11, and 12 so I want to have the SUM of the TYPE A, B, C through 3 years and their percentage (over the total) in that particular year.

Comment: yes, I do not want to make thing over complicated - 3 years should be sufficient now.  I think we could do something with dynamic pivot or something to have the table grows as the data grows

Comment: Related: [*Conditional sum in Group By query MSSQL*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16517298/3357935)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using SQL Server, if you are using SQL Server 2005+ then you can use the PIVOT function to get the result.  This solution implements both an unpivot and a pivot process to get the result. The starting point for this result is to calculate the total percent and total by type:

```
select type, year, total,
  round(total / sum(total) over(partition by year)*100.0, 1) t_per,
  sum(total) over(partition by type) t_type,
  round(sum(total) over(partition by type)*100.0/sum(total) over(), 1) tot_per      
from tablea
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/51656/36). This will give a result with multiple columns that you want to pivot so you can unpivot the data into multiple rows using CROSS APPLY:

```
select type, 
  col = cast(year as varchar(4))+'_'+col,
  value,
  t_type
from 
(
  select type, year, total,
    round(total / sum(total) over(partition by year)*100.0, 1) t_per,
    sum(total) over(partition by type) t_type,
    round(sum(total) over(partition by type)*100.0/sum(total) over(), 1) tot_per   
  from tablea
) d
cross apply
(
  select 'total', total union all
  select 't_per', t_per 
) c (col, value);
```

See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/51656/37).  Finally you can apply the PIVOT function to the values in `col`:

```
select type, 
  [2010_total], [2010_t_per],
  [2011_total], [2011_t_per],
  [2012_total], [2012_t_per],
  t_type,
  tot_per
from
(
  select type, 
    col = cast(year as varchar(4))+'_'+col,
    value,
    t_type,
    tot_per
  from 
  (
    select type, year, total,
      round(total / sum(total) over(partition by year)*100.0, 1) t_per,
      sum(total) over(partition by type) t_type,
      round(sum(total) over(partition by type)*100.0/sum(total) over(), 1) tot_per      
    from tablea 
  ) d
  cross apply
  (
    select 'total', total union all
    select 't_per', t_per 
  ) c (col, value)
) s
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for col in ([2010_total], [2010_t_per],
              [2011_total], [2011_t_per],
              [2012_total], [2012_t_per])
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/51656/38). This could be refactored to use a CTE instead of the subqueries and this could also be converted to use dynamic SQL if the year will be unknown.

If you have an unknown number of values, then the dynamic SQL code will be:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(cast(year as varchar(4))+'_'+col) 
                    from tablea
                    cross apply
                    (
                      select 'total', 1 union all
                      select 't_per', 2 
                    ) c (col, so)
                    group by year, col, so
                    order by year, so
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT type,' + @cols + ', t_type, tot_per
            from 
            (
              select type, 
                col = cast(year as varchar(4))+''_''+col,
                value,
                t_type,
                tot_per
              from 
              (
                select type, year, total,
                  round(total / sum(total) over(partition by year)*100.0, 1) t_per,
                  sum(total) over(partition by type) t_type,
                  round(sum(total) over(partition by type)*100.0/sum(total) over(), 1) tot_per      
                from tablea 
              ) d
              cross apply
              (
                select ''total'', total union all
                select ''t_per'', t_per 
              ) c (col, value)
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(value)
                for col in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute sp_executesql @query;
```

See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/51656/53).  Both the static version and the dynamic version give the result:

```
| TYPE | 2010_TOTAL | 2010_T_PER | 2011_TOTAL | 2011_T_PER | 2012_TOTAL | 2012_T_PER | T_TYPE | TOT_PER |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    A |          1 |       16.7 |          1 |       16.7 |          1 |       16.7 |      3 |    16.7 |
|    B |          2 |       33.3 |          2 |       33.3 |          2 |       33.3 |      6 |    33.3 |
|    C |          3 |         50 |          3 |         50 |          3 |         50 |      9 |      50 |
```

Answer (score 4):

`SUMIF` can be replicated in SQL with `SUM(case statement)`:

```
SELECT Type
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN Year = '2010' THEN Total ELSE 0 END)'2010 Total'
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN Year = '2010' THEN Total ELSE 0 END)*1.0/SUM(SUM(CASE WHEN Year = '2010' THEN Total ELSE 0 END)) OVER () '2010 Percent of Total'
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN Year = '2011' THEN Total ELSE 0 END)'2011 Total'
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN Year = '2011' THEN Total ELSE 0 END)*1.0/SUM(SUM(CASE WHEN Year = '2011' THEN Total ELSE 0 END)) OVER () '2011 Percent of Total'
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN Year = '2012' THEN Total ELSE 0 END)'2012 Total'
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN Year = '2012' THEN Total ELSE 0 END)*1.0/SUM(SUM(CASE WHEN Year = '2012' THEN Total ELSE 0 END)) OVER () '2012 Percent of Total'
      ,SUM(Total) 'Total'
      ,SUM(Total)*1.0/SUM(SUM(Total)) OVER () 'Percent of Total'

FROM Table
GROUP BY Type
```

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of simplicity I would prefer to show this result vertically:

```
SELECT 
Type, 
Year, 
SUM(Total) as Dollars,
ROUND(SUM(Total) * 100 / (SELECT SUM(TOTAL) FROM TableA t2 WHERE t2.Year = t1.Year),1) as Per
FROM TableA t1
Group By Type, Year
```

**Output:**

```
   TYPE YEAR    DOLLARS PERCENT

   A    2010    1   16.7
   B    2010    2   33.3
   C    2010    3   50
   A    2011    1   16.7
   B    2011    2   33.3
   C    2011    3   50
   A    2012    1   16.7
   B    2012    2   33.3
   C    2012    3   50
```

[Sql Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/51656/48)

Comment: thank but it does not do the trick of having the table horizontally but vertical.

Comment: @user2103670 What do you want exactly? This is returning the type, year and total for all your records. ;)

Comment: @FabianBigler OP provided result table, there are 9 columns but you have only 3.

Comment: I would like to have them in column format "2010","2011", "2012" next to each other instead of row by row

Comment: @user2103670 Is there a reason to do this? Because it's much easier the other way around. :)

Comment: In my company, we generally do not care much about how easy we should do it but we always want to look cool (not me but my bossesss)

Comment: @user2103670 yeah I see. Then bluefeet's answer is much more appropriate here. ;)