# Creating SumIf function in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need some help building a SQL Server function that acts as a `SumIf` in Excel, for example

```
SumIF(Fees.Fee_Amount, Fees.Type ='Services' and Fees.Fee_Code = 'B01')
```

so the item that would be summed if it is a `Fees.Fee_Amount` and the where part is `Fees.Type ='Services'` and `Fees.Fee_Code = 'B01'`

Syntax would be `SumIf(TableName.ColumnName, Criteria)`, the function would return the total.

Comment: Related: [*Conditional sum in Group By query MSSQL*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16517298/3357935)

Answer (score 34):

The simplest way would be to SUM a CASE clause, like so:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN Fees.Type ='Services' and Fees.Fee_Code = 'B01'
         THEN Fees.Fee_Amount
    END) AS ColumnAlias,
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, can you help me with scripting whole function?

Comment: You should add ' ELSE 0' because where condition not met should assign a value to sum