# Select data with the different filters in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, vb.net

I have this table named `expenses` with the fallowing fields `refnum, transdate, transtype, transcategory, amount`

this table has the following data

```
refnum | transdate  | transtype | transcategory |     amount 
 1     | 10/10/2015 |  cash-out |     null      |    5000.00 
 1     | 10/10/2015 |  cash-in  |     null      |    3000.00 
 1     | 10/10/2015 |  cash-in  |     null      |    1000.00 
 2     | 10/10/2015 |  cash-out |     null      |    5000.00 
 2     | 10/10/2015 |  cash-in  |     null      |    3000.00 
 2     | 10/10/2015 |  cash-in  |     null      |    2000.00
 3     | 10/10/2015 |  cash-out |     null      |    5000.00
 3     | 10/10/2015 |  cash-in  |     null      |    5000.00
```

The question is: Is it possible to get the balance of the amount base on its `transtype and refnum`

I have this query:

```
SELECT 
    A.refnum, A.transtype, A.amount,(A.amount-B.amount) as balance 
FROM 
    expenses AS A 
INNER JOIN
    expenses AS B ON A.refnum = B.refnum 
WHERE
    A.transtype = 'cash-in' 
    AND B.transtype = 'cash-out' 
    AND (A.amount - B.amount) > 0
```

I am confused, this query I think is good if `cash-in` is exactly the same as the amount of `cash-out` but the problem is almost all `cash-in` is not the same amount of `cash-out`, hope you guys understand what i am asking for.

I need the query that will show only with the `refnum` of `1`.

Is it possible?

Comment: something like `SELECT refnum, SUM(CASE WHEN transtype='cash-out' then -amount ELSE amount  END)) from expenses GROUP BY refnum`

Comment: Hello pretty welcome to StackOverflow, next time try to provide a 
[**SqlFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5368b/6) so we can help you faster and better – Also please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
And for sql questions please include your rdbms and data sample with input and desire output.

Comment: Nice, thanks for the time @JuanCarlosOropeza

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, thanks i will try your suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like Nick say:

Using [**conditional with aggregated methods**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/310674/Conditional-Sums-in-SQL-Aggregate-Methods)

another [**example**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16517298/conditional-sum-in-group-by-query-mssql)

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/beea20/4)

- `group by` will separate your data into groups, in this case a group for each refnum (1,2,3) [**GROUP BY**](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)
- `conditional SUM`: A normal `SUM(amount)` will give you that, the SUM of the whole group you define above. But not all amount are positive. So you use the `CASE` statement to change `amount` to `-amount` `WHEN transtype='cash-out'`

.

```
SELECT 
    refnum, 
    SUM(CASE 
            WHEN transtype='cash-out' then -amount 
            ELSE amount 
        END)  as total
FROM expenses 
GROUP BY refnum
```

---

**Edit**

For your reference this is a way using CTE and Join

- CTE or [**Common Table Expressions**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx): Allow you create subqueries so you can use it on other queries. Works like creating a temporal table so you can do select or join over that result.
- In this case I create two table `cash_out` and `cash_in` each one contain the value of the sum for each refnum.
- After I wrote it i realize if one refnum doesn't have `cash_in` or `cash_out` this won't work. So I add another subquery to include all the `refnum` and perform a `left join` that way if not data the join will still work and add 0.
- [**ISNULL(variable,0)**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms190349(v=sql.120).aspx): return `variable` if `variable <> null` or 0 otherwise

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a83fcc/2)

```
WITH ref as (
    SELECT DISTINCT refnum
    FROM expenses
),
cash_out as (    
    SELECT A.refnum, SUM(A.amount) balance 
    FROM 
        expenses AS A 
        where A.transtype = 'cash-out'
    GROUP BY A.refnum
),
cash_in as (
    SELECT A.refnum, SUM(A.amount) balance 
    FROM 
        expenses AS A 
        where A.transtype = 'cash-in' 
    GROUP BY A.refnum
)
SELECT cin.refnum, (ISNULL(cin.balance,0) - ISNULL(cout.balance,0)) as total
FROM 
   ref r LEFT JOIN
   cash_in cin on r.refnum = cin.refnum LEFT JOIN
   cash_out cout on r.refnum = cout.refnum
```

Comment: For you I include an example using CTE and Join. Same results but need more work. I probably did it that way if didnt know conditional agregation. One important step you miss was `group by`

Comment: Your answer @Juan Carlos Oropeza works perfectly but don't know how it works. i am not satisfied if i don't know how it works. do you have the link that explain that lines of codes? sorry, i am new in terms of programming. i just want to explore and study more about sql. i really appreciate your effort..

Comment: and by the way how can i turn the result into possitive?

Comment: I update my answer and my fiddle with more explain. Let me know if still are something you don't understand.

Comment: Don't understand your question about result possitive show me an example.

Comment: This is a great answer @Juan Carlos Oropeza you solve my problem.. thanks to all who take time to read my question and answer it..  This question is now solved.