# union of two queries in one

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select

I have two queries with different result sets but only one of the conditions is additional in one of the queries. Both queries are fetching from the same table.
first query:

```
SELECT cm.ctm, count_big(*) AS TOTAL
                       FROM dbo_cm.cm
                       WHERE 
                          cm.a= 'abc' AND 
                          cm.b= 1 AND 
                          cm.ps IS NOT NULL AND 
                          datepart(MONTH, cm.ps) = 7 AND 
                          datepart(YEAR, cm.ps) = 2015  
                       GROUP BY cm.ctm
```

second query:

```
SELECT cm.ctm, count_big(*) AS TOTAL
                       FROM dbo_cm.cm
                       WHERE 
                          cm.a= 'abc' AND 
                          cm.b= 1 AND 
                          cm.ps IS NOT NULL AND 
                          datepart(MONTH, cm.ps) = 7 AND 
                          datepart(YEAR, cm.ps) = 2015 and
                          cm.as>cm.ps
                       GROUP BY cm.ctm
```

How do I make this query simpler by merging it into one? We use `decode` in Oracle for this purpose.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conditional sum in Group By query MSSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16517298/conditional-sum-in-group-by-query-mssql)

Answer (score 3):

You can merge these two queries into one by moving the additional condition in the second query to a `case` expression and returning `null` when the condition is not met. `count_big`, like any aggregate function, will just ignore the `null`s:

```
SELECT   cm.ctm, 
         COUNT_BIG(*) AS total1,
         COUNT_BIG(CASE WHEN cm.as > cm.ps THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS total2
FROM     dbo_cm.cm
WHERE    cm.a= 'abc' AND 
         cm.b= 1 AND 
         cm.ps IS NOT NULL AND 
         DATEPART(MONTH, cm.ps) = 7 AND 
         DATEPART(YEAR, cm.ps) = 2015 AND
GROUP BY cm.ctm
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SUM(CASE...)` like:

```
SELECT
   cm.ctm,
   count_big(*) AS TOTAL1,
   SUM(CASE WHEN cm.[as]>cm.[ps] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TOTAL2
FROM dbo_cm.cm
WHERE cm.a= 'abc'
  AND cm.b= 1 
  AND cm.ps IS NOT NULL
  AND datepart(MONTH, cm.ps) = 7
  AND datepart(YEAR, cm.ps) = 2015  
GROUP BY cm.ctm
```