# How I can create a query like that without pivot?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Really, I would like to someone can help me with this query. I want to get this how the example. I dont want to use "Pivot". I have a lit of items called 'Serie' this obviously need a group by, because this repeat too many times that's why I am grouping it. So each one of the item of the field "serie" has a list of codes from 001 until 100 then I just want to get the min number of that list, so"001" and max number so "100" for each one of the months.

Please help me with it,
Thanks in advance.

Example :

```
SERIE               JAN     FEB       MAR    APRI   MAY     JUN     JUL
                    D | H  D | H     D | H  D | H   D | H   D | H   D | H

Recibo CA           01  10 02  50   01  10 02  50
Recibo VA-03        04  20 05  80
Recibo UV           08  40 03  10
Recibo VA-02
Recibo VA-04
Recibo VA-01
Recibo WH
Factura 0003
```

[image]

My data in my database is like it shows here.

```
 Id     Serie        Month   Serie number
    1   Factura 0003    Jan     4771           
    2   Factura 0003    Jan     4779           
    3   Factura 0003    Jan     4792           
    4   Factura 0003    Febr    4864           
    5   Factura 0003    Febr    4892
```

Comment: Please there is the image if you have doubts .

Comment: Use CASE expressions. e.g. `SELECT SERIE, CASE WHEN x THEN y END [col1]...`

Comment: And why don't you want to use pivot?

Comment: Do you have access to ssrs?

Comment: If you dont want pivot, you can do that using `CASE WHEN` condition.. search for "Conditional Aggregation" , something like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16517298/conditional-sum-in-group-by-query-mssql

Comment: Thanks so much for their answers. This website is the best of all, I can not use Pivot for set compatibility. It seems, they have a different compatibility to accept this sentece. I have tried activate it but it not works. So I prefer to use another way because I am not administrator of the database. Japonskie thanks ....

Answer (score 0):

You can emulate Pivot through diagonal matrix multiplication:

```
With test ([Id], [Serie], [Month], [Serie number])
As (
    Select 1, 'Factura 0003', 'Jan', 4771 Union
    Select 2, 'Factura 0003', 'Jan', 4779 Union
    Select 3, 'Factura 0003', 'Jan', 4792 Union
    Select 4, 'Factura 0003', 'Feb', 4864 Union
    Select 5, 'Factura 0003', 'Feb', 4892
), diagonal_matrics ([Month], [Jan], [Feb], [Mar], [Apr], [May], [Jun], [Jul], [Aug], [Sep], [Oct], [Nov], [Dec])
As (
    Select 'Jan',    1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL Union
    Select 'Feb', NULL,    1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL Union
    Select 'Mar', NULL, NULL,    1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL Union
    Select 'Apr', NULL, NULL, NULL,    1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL Union
    Select 'May', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,    1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL Union
    Select 'Jun', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,    1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL Union
    Select 'Jul', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,    1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL Union
    Select 'Aug', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,    1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL Union
    Select 'Sep', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,    1, NULL, NULL, NULL Union
    Select 'Oct', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,    1, NULL, NULL Union
    Select 'Nov', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,    1, NULL Union
    Select 'Dec', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,    1
)
Select [Serie],
    Min([Serie number] * [Jan]) [Jan Min], Max([Serie number] * [Jan]) [Jan Max],
    Min([Serie number] * [Feb]) [Feb Min], Max([Serie number] * [Feb]) [Feb Max],
    Min([Serie number] * [Mar]) [Mar Min], Max([Serie number] * [Mar]) [Mar Max],
    Min([Serie number] * [Apr]) [Apr Min], Max([Serie number] * [Apr]) [Apr Max],
    Min([Serie number] * [May]) [May Min], Max([Serie number] * [May]) [May Max],
    Min([Serie number] * [Jun]) [Jun Min], Max([Serie number] * [Jun]) [Jun Max],
    Min([Serie number] * [Jul]) [Jul Min], Max([Serie number] * [Jul]) [Jul Max],
    Min([Serie number] * [Aug]) [Aug Min], Max([Serie number] * [Aug]) [Aug Max],
    Min([Serie number] * [Sep]) [Sep Min], Max([Serie number] * [Sep]) [Sep Max],
    Min([Serie number] * [Oct]) [Oct Min], Max([Serie number] * [Oct]) [Oct Max],
    Min([Serie number] * [Nov]) [Nov Min], Max([Serie number] * [Nov]) [Nov Max],
    Min([Serie number] * [Dec]) [Dec Min], Max([Serie number] * [Dec]) [Dec Max]
From test
Inner Join diagonal_matrics On test.[Month] = diagonal_matrics.[Month]
Group By [Serie]
```

Comment: Hi, Y.B. thanks for your asnswer but understand more or less your logic. In order in the first lines. That means I am going to write all says in my database for emalute "Pivot" because I have in my table thousandsss of records. Sure till now they are "Recibos" different kinds (8) and each one has all the months of year ...

Comment: @JosephMarchena This is just a way to include test data into the example. Use the actual table instead of `test` Common Table Expression in you database.