# SQL percentage of salary by each employee in different location

Tags: sql

I got some difficulty when I am trying to get the Salary % of each employee that work in different locations, and by using that % to calculate employee salary contribution in each location. I've attached the table structure and expected result below. I am trying to use the following query, but I think I missed something to group them together. There are errors in the query. Can anybody help me with this?

[image: Table Structure and Expected Result]

```
SELECT p.[Period End Date], p.[EE#], p.Department, 
(p.[Gross Wages]/ SUM([Gross Wages])) 
WHERE [Location] = 'A' AS 'Gross Wages % in Location A',
(p.[Gross Wages]/ SUM[Gross Wages]) 
WHERE [Location] = 'B' AS 'Gross Wages % in Location B',
b.[Health Insurance]*(p.[Gross Wages]/ SUM[Gross Wages]) 
WHERE [Location] = 'A' AS 'Health Insurance % in Location A',
b.[Health Insurance]*(p.[Gross Wages]/ SUM[Gross Wages]) 
WHERE [Location] = 'B' AS 'Health Insurance % in Location B',
c.[Tax]*(p.[Gross Wages]/ SUM[Gross Wages]) 
WHERE [Location] = 'A' AS 'Tax % in Location A',
c.[Tax]*(p.[Gross Wages]/ SUM[Gross Wages]) 
WHERE [Location] = 'B' AS 'Tax % in Location B',
FROM [Table A] p
INNER JOIN [Table B] b ON p.[Employee Number] = b.[Employee Number]
INNER JOIN [Table C] b ON p.[Employee Number] = c.[Employee Number]
GROUP BY p.[location]
Order by p.[Employee Number]
    INNER JOIN [Table B] b ON p.[Employee Number] = b.[Employee Number]
    INNER JOIN [Table C] b ON p.[Employee Number] = c.[Employee Number]
    GROUP BY p.[location]
    Order by p.[Employee Number]
```

Query Edited Update.
Errors:
1. Found Else by expected ')' Line 2
2. Found 'Gross Wages % in Location A' but expected ''. Line 2
3. Found 'Gross Wages % in Location A' but expected ''. Line 2

```
SELECT p.[Period End Date], p.[EE#], p.Department, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN [Location]='A' THEN(p.[Gross Wages]/ SUM([Gross Wages]) ELSE '0' END) AS 'Gross Wages % in Location A'),
    SUM(CASE WHEN [Location]='B' THEN(p.[Gross Wages]/ SUM([Gross Wages]) ELSE '0' END) AS 'Gross Wages % in Location B'),
    SUM(CASE WHEN [Location]='A' THEN(b.[Health Insurance]*(p.[Gross Wages]/SUM([Gross Wages]) ELSE '0' END) AS 'Health Insurance in Location A'),
    SUM(CASE WHEN [Location]='B' THEN(b.[Health Insurance]*(p.[Gross Wages]/ SUM([Gross Wages]) ELSE '0' END) AS 'Health Insurance in Location B'),
    SUM(CASE WHEN [Location]='A' THEN(b.[Tax]*(p.[Gross Wages]/ SUM[Gross Wages]) ELSE '0' END) AS 'Tax in Location A'),
    SUM(CASE WHEN [Location]='B' THEN(b.[Tax]*(p.[Gross Wages]/ SUM[Gross Wages]) ELSE '0' END) AS 'Tax in Location B'),
FROM [Table A] p
INNER JOIN [Table B] b ON p.[EE#] = b.[EE#]
INNER JOIN [Table C] b ON p.[EE#] = c.[EE#]
GROUP BY p.[EE#], p.[location]
ORDER BY p.[EE#]
```

Comment: Wow those table names are just awful. Which DBMS are you actually using? sql server <> mysql. Also, can you provide more details than "there are error in the query"? Logical errors? Syntax errors? Help us understand the problem.

Comment: That's not where the `WHERE` clauses goes. Look into a `CASE` expression instead, [like here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16517352/6167855)

Comment: @scsimon wow I didn't even notice the where clauses through the wall of text.

Comment: HAHA @SeanLange I was kind of shocked you didn't mention it...

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: @scsimon, you probably mean case expression.

Comment: That GROUP BY seems to be invalid. The general GROUP BY rule says:
If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function.

Comment: There are so many things wrong in this single query it is hard to name them all. Multiple where clauses, incomplete group by, multiple aliases with the same name, trailing comma after the last column. Aliases referenced that don't exist. This thing is a total train wreck. You need to start from scratch on this query. If you need help here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: I removed the incompatible database names.

Comment: The `where` clause needs to go **after** the `from` and `join` clauses

Comment: I used MySQL in SQLServer

Comment: it is not possible to use mysql in sqlserver -- but a very funny comment.  Your data model does not Employee Number in any of the tables -- how can your joins work?

Comment: Sorry, that's my bad, I changed my data structure in the sample to put in here. The table name is not real, just for sample used.

Comment: @Angel -- almost always a bad idea unless you **TEST YOUR EXAMPLE** which you clearly didn't do.  However, I've seen this problem many times before so my code below should show you the best way to solve the problem.

Comment: Your second query has many errors -- for example you alias two tables to the same name, you specify column names without alias, etc

Answer (score 0):

Making a lot of guesses about what is going on but this should be close:

The key thing I'm doing below is to use JOINing to flatten the result and reduce the CASE statements.  Here instead of having to do two case statements and a group by you just have two joins and then use the correct one for the column's calculation.

```
SELECT 
  P.[EE#], P.location,
--  p.[Period End Date], 
--  p.[EE#], p.Department,
  (AA.[Gross Wages]/ SUM(AA.[Gross Wages])  AS 'Gross Wages % in Location A',
  (AB.[Gross Wages]/ SUM(AB.[Gross Wages])  AS 'Gross Wages % in Location B',
  BA.[Health Insurance]*(AA.[Gross Wages]/ SUM(AA.[Gross Wages])) AS 'Health insurance Location A',
  BB.[Health Insurance]*(AB.[Gross Wages]/ SUM(AB.[Gross Wages])) AS 'Health insurance Location B'
-- etc something with CA and CB
FROM (SELECT distinct [EE#], location FROM [Table A]) AS P
LEFT JOIN [TABLE A] AA ON p.[EE#] = AA.[EE#] AND BA.Location = 'A'
LEFT JOIN [TABLE A] AB ON p.[EE#] = AB.[EE#] AND BB.Location = 'B'
LEFT JOIN [TABLE B] BA ON p.[EE#] = BA.[EE#] AND BA.Location = 'A'
LEFT JOIN [TABLE B] BB ON p.[EE#] = BB.[EE#] AND BB.Location = 'B'
LEFT JOIN [TABLE C] CA ON p.[EE#] = CA.[EE#] AND CA.Location = 'A'
LEFT JOIN [TABLE C] CB ON p.[EE#] = CB.[EE#] AND CB.Location = 'B'
GROUP BY p.[EE#], p.[location]
Order by p.[EE#]
```

Also note:

I would expect you would want the following query to get all the EE#s not just the ones in [Table A]:

```
FROM (
  SELECT distinct [EE#], location FROM [Table A]
  UNION
  SELECT distinct [EE#], location FROM [Table B]
  UNION
  SELECT distinct [EE#], location FROM [Table C]
) AS P
```

of course if you have an employee table somewhere that would be even better then you could do something like

```
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [EE#], location FROM Employee) AS P
```

Then if you have employees who are not in A, B or C -- they would still show up in your report.

Comment: Thank you for the that! I've created a query table to DISTINCT all the employee no.

Comment: Get it! I will try this out! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with the join. I wonder if I distinct the location, date and the employee no., how can I join them in the code since I have DISTINCT them?

Comment: @Angel I don't don't know, I don't understand your question -- I'd have to see your code to know for sure.  If you can't post it here (which is best) you can use a private gist (gist.github.com) or email (in my profile).