# SQL function to replicate SUMIF in my Excel

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel-formula, sumifs

I am new to SQL Server 2012 and want to minimize data handling in Excel.

I have my main data set and then I want to do a SUMIF from those data, and return only the rows that sumif not equal to zero.

I use following function and it returns different results at different times.

Possible reason for error is that there are some rows that AccID is blank.

```
, main_data2 as 
(

    select
            md.*

    from main_data md
    left join
    (
            select 
                AccID
                ,sum(amount) as total_amount
            from main_data
            group by AccID
            having sum(amount) <> 0 

) md2 on md.AccID = md2.AccID

where md2.AccID is null

)
```

Comment: I need to include those rows that AccID is empty in my final results.

Comment: Now you are changing your requirements.  Do you want only records whose accounts have a non-zero sum, or do you want _all_ records?  If the latter, then what is the point of the subquery?

Comment: Related: [*Conditional sum in Group By query MSSQL*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16517298/3357935)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retain all accounts in the final result set, then a `LEFT JOIN` would seem to be appropriate.  The subquery you already have finds those accounts with a non zero sum.  You can left join `main_data` to this subquery and then optionally label each record as being empty should its corresponding account sum be zero.

```
SELECT
    md.*,
    CASE WHEN md2.AccID IS NULL THEN 'Empty' END AS label
FROM main_data md
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT AccID, SUM(amount) AS total_amount
    FROM main_data
    GROUP BY AccID
    HAVING SUM(amount) <> 0 
) md2
    ON md.AccID = md2.AccID
```

Comment: I don't need all results in my final result. Only need the ones with non-zero sumif balance and the ones with no accountID at all (So I can process them manually).

In terms data load usually half a million data there and after sumif it should only return about 5000 line items. This process is trying to avoid that large data handling in excel.

Comment: `ones with no accountID at all` ... this doesn't make sense because you're doing a self-join.  The set of account IDs is in principle the same in both sides of the join.

Comment: Ah got your point, as I mentioned I am new to SQL and in Excel when u got a blank cell and when you do sumif it returns 0. But your point is right no need to worry about that in here.

Comment: If you show us your expected output, maybe I can alter my answer in some way.