# Conditional sum in group by varaibale result table size

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, pivot

I have a follow up question on a very interesting question about conditional sums in group by queries which I came upon on SO. Here is the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16517298/conditional-sum-in-group-by-query-mssql).

**The orignal question**

I have a table OrderDetails with the following schema:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
|  OrderId  |  CopyCost  |  FullPrice  |  Price  |  PriceType  |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|  16       |  50        |  100        |  50     |  CopyCost   |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|  16       |  50        |  100        |  100    |  FullPrice  |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|  16       |  50        |  100        |  50     |  CopyCost   |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|  16       |  50        |  100        |  50     |  CopyCost   |
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

I need a query that will surmise the above table into a new table with the following schema:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
|  OrderId  |  ItemCount  |  TotalCopyCost  |  TotalFullPrice  |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|  16       |  4          |  150            |  100             |
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Currently I am using a Group By on the Order.Id to the the item count. But I do not know how to conditionally surmise the CopyCost and FullPrice values.

**The follow up**

Is there any way to do this if you don't know the price types in advance? For example if the table in question `| OrderId | CopyCost | FullPrice | Price | PriceType |` would be the result of a join on an `order` table and an `order_price_type` table? The summary table would then have a changing column count depending on how many rows the `order_price_types` table has?

Would this be using sql for something which it wasn't designed for and better done in code?

Comment: "*The summary table would then have a changing column count*" - that's not possible. The number of columns must known _before_ a SQL statement is executed. What you want is know as [pivot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postgresql+sql+pivot)  or [crosstab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postgresql+sql+crosstab) and has been asked and answered many times

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks I was looking for pivot. If you already wrote an answer to this somewhere you could link to it in an answer. Alternatively copy it here.