# TSQL query to get the Difference of values of same column for different WHERE clause by joining two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Below is the sample query which gives the rating by employee and manager from two different tables.

```sql
SELECT pr.[task_id],
       pr.[user_rating],ts.[title]
FROM [dbo].[rpt_task] ts
      INNER JOIN [dbo].[rpt_review] pr ON ts.[task_id] = pr.[task_id]
WHERE ts.[culture_id] = 1
```

[image: Sample output]

Now, I am trying to draft the query where the result be like

Sample Desired Output - [  variance being(user_rating of 'Manager review' - user_rating of 'self_Review')

```
task_id   variance
6095      0
```

I have tried as

```sql
SELECT pr.[task_id],
       ((SELECT pr.[user_rating]
         FROM [dbo].[rpt_task] ts
              INNER JOIN [dbo].[rpt_review] pr ON ts.[task_id] = pr.[task_id]
         WHERE ts.[title] = 'Manager Review') -
        (SELECT pr.[user_rating]
         FROM [dbo].[rpt_task] ts
              INNER JOIN [dbo].[rpt_review] pr ON ts.[task_id] = pr.[task_id]
         WHERE ts.[title] = 'Self Review'))
FROM [dbo].[rpt_task] ts
      INNER JOIN [dbo].[rpt_review] pr ON ts.[task_id] = pr.[task_id]  
WHERE ts.[culture_id] = 1
GROUP BY pr.[task_id]
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to `JOIN` to the same table 3 times in the bottom query and giving the table the *same* alias each time; that won't work. A table's alias most be unique within the same scope.

Comment: Also, learn to make *good* use of whitespace and line breaks. Both your queries are quite difficult to read due to a lack of both.

Comment: Well, now with some formatting we can see that you are reusing aliasing in the subqueries instead; not a good habit. I suggest changing the aliases of the objects in the subqueries in the `SELECT` so as not to confuse people. You have *5* references to `pr.[task_id]` and *3* of them reference the same instance of it, and the other 2 completely separate (and different) ones....

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conditional sum in Group By query MSSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16517298/conditional-sum-in-group-by-query-mssql). After you have ratings in a row, you can apply any function to them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **ASSUMPTION**: You didn't provide the table structure of the underlying tables, hence I'm assuming that the `rpt_review` table doesn't need to be joined twice, as there's one record there, and one record for each reviewer in the `rpt_task` table.
> Please correct me if this assumption isn't correct.

You'll need to self-join the table in order to get both the manager and the self reviews. I've joined both of them to the `rpt_review` table and did the math as you were trying to do.

Sample Code:

```
SELECT 
     pr.[task_id]
    ,ts_manager.[user_rating] - ts_self.[user_rating] AS Variance
FROM [dbo].[rpt_task] ts_self
INNER JOIN [dbo].[rpt_review] pr ON ts.[task_id] = pr.[task_id]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[rpt_task] ts_manager ON ts_self.culture_id = ts_manager.culture_id
WHERE ts_self.[culture_id] = 1
AND ts_self.[title] = 'Self Review'
AND ts_manager.[title] = 'Manager Review';
```