# Efficient Multiple Max Values in MSSQL Select

Tags: sql-server, max

I have 2 tables in MSSQL.

| test | method |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 1 | C |
| 2 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | A |

| method | version | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | Retired |
| A | 2 | Released |
| A | 3 | Draft |
| B | 1 | Released |
| B | 2 | Draft |
| C | 1 | Draft |

For a given test, I want a list of the related methods, the maximum draft version and the maximum released version.

So I would expect:

| test | method | max_draft | max_released |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 3 | 2 |
| 1 | B | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | C | 1 | null |
| 2 | A | 3 | 2 |
| 2 | B | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | A | 1 | null |

if there was no where clause.

This works for me, but is clearly not efficient. What is the best way to do this as my understanding you cannot have separate conditions for multiple over/ partition by statements within a single select statement:

```
select  A.TEST,
        A.METHOD,
        (Select Max(Version) from B where STATUS = 'Draft' and METHOD = A.METHOD) as max_draft,
        (Select Max(Version) from B where STATUS = 'Released' and METHOD = A.METHOD) as max_released
        

from A
join B on A.METHOD = B.METHOD
```

To be clear, I need multiple other fields from both tables too, the above is a cut down version.

Comment: Have you considered using conditional aggregation?

Comment: You don't need the `JOIN` in your query. Don't assume every subquery will result in an extra JOIN either. Inspect the execution plan. If `Status` and `Method` are indexed the query engine *could* generate the results in a single pass. You could use a PIVOT clause but that wouldn't be more efficient or cleaner to write

Comment: @Larnu - that's exaclty what it needs isn't it? I'm just struggling for the syntax here. Can you advise?

Comment: This syntax is identical as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16517298/2029983); you just want `MAX` not `SUM`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos sorry, yes in the example here you are right, in the real world however, I need a bunch of other fields from that table too, hence the join.

Comment: @Larnu this only works when I just want the 2 Max values, unfortunately I need multiple other columns from both tables too.

Comment: If you want more conditional `MAX` columns *add* more conditional `MAX` columns, @JamesChappell ... Just because the example has 2 doesn't mean you're limited to 2...

Comment: @Larnu I don't need multiple Max columns, just more columns from table B. When I do, I get the standard aggregate error: Column 'B.XXX' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Have you added the columns you aren't aggregating to the `GROUP BY` like the link answer shows?

Comment: @Larnu yes, I have done that now and it works. Essentially any column from table B must be aggregated to avoid duplicate rows. Thank you.

Is there a way I can do this avoiding having to aggregate all columns for table B?