# How to write SQl query to find the below output

Tags: sql-server

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEsJu.png)

Can anyone please help in getting the attached output?

**Student Table**

```
**Name  Subject Marks**
Joan    Maths   60
Joan    Engish  80
Joan    Science 70
Ray     Maths   100
Ray     Engish  90
Ray     Science 75
Mike    Maths   85
Mike    Engish  95
Mike    Science 88
Ashley  Maths   69
Ashley  Engish  77
Ashley  Science 97
```

Output will be

**Output**

```
StudentName Maths   Engish  Science
Joan         60     80       70
Ray          100    90       75
Mike         85     95       88
Ashley       69     77       97
```

Comment: You need to help yourself first. Make some effort. Do some research, try and solve the problem yourself. Then, after all your efforts have failed, then ask a question explaining your goal, providing **consumable** sample data (not images), include your attempts and/or details of the research your did, and what about your attempts didn't work or what about your research you didn't understand. [so] isn't a free coding service, so don't expect users here to just do your work for you; they won't.

Comment: Now we just need a description of the goal(s), your attempt(s) or details of your research, and the details of the difficulty you're having.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conditional sum in Group By query MSSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16517298/conditional-sum-in-group-by-query-mssql)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
select [Name],
min(case when seq = 1 then  marks end) Maths,
min(case when seq = 2 then  marks end) Engish,
min(case when seq = 3 then  marks end) Science
from
(
select [Name],[subject],marks,
row_number() over(partition by [Name] order by [subject]) seq
from Student
) d
group by [Name];
```

Comment: Your code "works" only when every student is associated with the same set of subjects. To see this in action, remove just one row (any one - doesn't matter) from your sample data.

Comment: the above query is not giving the correct output.

Comment: select Names, 
       max(case when Subjects = 'Maths' then Marks end) as Maths_mark, 
       max(case when Subjects = 'Science' then Marks end) as Science_mark,
       max(case when Subjects = 'Engish' then Marks end) as English_mark
from Student s 
group by Names;